# I cannot render {cp_session_id} in edit this like

Tags: ee2, control-panel

I am trying to make edit entry link using this idea in user guide bellow

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#cp-session-id

but {cp_session_id} variable is not rendering in the page, any ideas ?

{if logged_in_group_id == "1" OR logged_in_group_id == "2" }• Edit This{/if}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be the S=0 part. That does only work if you have control panel security set to cookie only. By default the CP is set to Session_id too. For session_id to work with "edit" links from the front-end, you currently need to get the fingerprint / session_id with a little add-on (or with PHP, which i'm not a fan of in templates).

Here is a small plugin i created and use for this
https://gist.github.com/GDmac/8095086

(edit: issue is accepted, but is not in current EE.
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19501
with php in template work-around)

Comment: totally fix my problem and safe my day :)
thanks allot GDmac

Comment: the most easy fix is to set cp to cookie only :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you are logged into the control panel at www.domain.com/system/ and looking at the front-end of the site using domain.com (without www). If this is the case, EE doesn't consider you "logged in". You can change this in two ways...

---

Force either www.domain.com or domain.com in the htaccess file

```
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]   
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`
```

Then log into the control panel again if needed.

---

Set the [**cookie domain**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/cookie_settings.html#cookie-domain) in the EE CP to `.domain.com`... (change domain.com to your domain)

Comment: I would like to thank you for your help
I did all changes you told me, but Unfortunately, it did not work for me .
in my case I have to log-in every time I need to edit any entry. :(